# Dealing with an API with a lot of data

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for advice on how best to approach this. I am grabbing data from a third party API that doesn’t allow me to query/filter the data in the way I want.

That means I am required to pull every single row of the data and then I cycle through the rows through my own custom endpoint returning the data that meets the criteria. This isn’t feasible on load of the site as it is around a million rows of data.

I figured that I could pull all the data daily and store it in my own database so I can query it however I like might be the best bet. Storing in a CSV would be a security risk and it’s too large I presume.

Is a database the best method of doing this?

My custom endpoints would query this database however I like as it gives me the flexibility to do so.

The source data via the API is returned as csv format and am using PHP.

Comment: Yes, that is the exact use case for a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case database will be better than csv, you can write query that match any criteria like sorting, paginate or adding filter.
its so hard to do all this operations in csv file. this will cause you load whole data in memory then add this filter so this operation cost will be high based on data size and not good performance comparing with database.